# how to pad comma separated string with php?

Tags: php

I have a variable with the following value:
`1,2,11,17,2`
I need to convert it to:
`SER1, SER2, SER11, SER17, SER2`
In other words I need to pad to the left of each number the words `SER`
How to accomplish this with PHP?

Comment: preg_replace is the function you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to replace each number with SER prepended to the number: `preg_replace('/(\d+)/', 'SER$1', '1,2,11,17,2');`

Comment: That did the trick!, So easy, yet so obvious!. +1 to @jhon-himmelman for quickness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_map](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to iterate through the array and prepend the string.

Example:

```
$array = array(1,2,11,17,2);

$new_array = array_map(function($value) {
    return 'STR' . $value;
}, $array);

var_dump($new_array);
```

**Edit:** Disregard, I thought you were working with an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenate for the first 'SER' and then use the replace function.

```
$StringVar="SER".$StringVar
$StringVar=str_replace(" ,",", SER",$StringVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example of array_walk, you see this code:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Before ...:
d. lemon
a. orange
b. banana
c. apple
... and after:
d. fruit: lemon
a. fruit: orange
b. fruit: banana
c. fruit: apple
```

Comment: You would have to convert the string to an array, first using explode();